# Creating list of examples using tocloft in memoir class

Tags: memoir, tocloft

I am trying to create a new "Examples" environment in the memoir class (which has the tocloft package, I believe), but I cannot get the list entries correct. The best I have is the following,

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newlength\Labelwidth
\newlength\AfterLabelspace
\setlength\Labelwidth{2em}
\setlength\AfterLabelspace{10pt}

\newtheorem{xexample}{Example}
\newcommand\listexamplesname{List of Examples}
\newlistof{listofexample}{loe}{\listexamplesname}
\newlistentry[chapter]{examplecounter}{loe}{0}
\newcommand{\edescription}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{examplecounter}
\par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexamplecounter~(#1).}
\addcontentsline{loe}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theexamplecounter}#1}}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\edescription{#1}}{\qed\par}

\newcounter{propcounter}[chapter]
\newenvironment{proposition}[1][]{\refstepcounter{propcounter} \noindent  {\bfseries Proposition \arabic{propcounter}  (#1).}}{\qed}

\begin{document}

\listofexample
\bigskip

\begin{example}[Big Idea]
Some big idea.
\end{example}

\begin{proposition}[Medium Idea]
Something hard.
\end{proposition}

\begin{example}[Small Idea]
Some small idea.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

This gives me the following:

[image]
which I'm happy with except that I want the list items (e.g., "0.1  ...") to be flush left the same way my figure and table lists are.

I also know that I should not be using

```
\addcontentsline{loe}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theexamplecounter}#1}}
```

but rather

```
\addcontentsline{loe}{listofexample}{\protect\numberline{\theexamplecounter}#1}}
```

But when I use "listofexample" instead of "section" I get,

[image]

which is junk.

**Question**: How do I use "listofexample" in `\addcontentsline` to get what I want? I know that `\newlistof` creates lots of extra macros, but I do not know which to use.

Thanks for anyone's help.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can disable the `tocloft` emulation by `memoir`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
\addcontentsline{loe}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theexamplecounter}#1}
```

which instruct memoir to format the entries as section entries (thus adding the same indention as for section entries in the ToC), use

```
\addcontentsline{loe}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\theexamplecounter}#1}
```

so the entries are formatted as figure entries. A complete example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newlength\Labelwidth
\newlength\AfterLabelspace
\setlength\Labelwidth{2em}
\setlength\AfterLabelspace{10pt}

\newtheorem{xexample}{Example}
\newcommand\listexamplesname{List of Examples}
\newlistof{listofexample}{loe}{\listexamplesname}
\newlistentry[chapter]{examplecounter}{loe}{0}
\newcommand{\edescription}[1]{%
\refstepcounter{examplecounter}
\par\noindent\textbf{Example \theexamplecounter~(#1).}
\addcontentsline{loe}{figure}{\protect\numberline{\theexamplecounter}#1}
}
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\edescription{#1}}{\qed\par}

\newcounter{propcounter}[chapter]
\newenvironment{proposition}[1][]{\refstepcounter{propcounter} \noindent  {\bfseries Proposition \arabic{propcounter}  (#1).}}{\qed}

\begin{document}

\listofexample
\bigskip

\begin{example}[Big Idea]
Some big idea.
\end{example}

\begin{proposition}[Medium Idea]
Something hard.
\end{proposition}

\begin{example}[Small Idea]
Some small idea.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! So obvious. With that change, I still find vertical spacing between lines to be too great, but I will sort that out with some vspace commands.

Comment: I would up vote the answer but don't have enough points to do so...

Comment: @xbot You're welcome. Don't worry; you can up-vote it later ;)